# Парсер сайта курл

Tags: curl

Хочу спарсить сайт с помощью курла. Но в результате выдает ошибку 302 Found nginx. Вот код:function curl($url)

```
   {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, " Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0
                .2564.109 Safari/537.36");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $output;
    }
     $auth = curl($link );

            $parser = phpQuery::newDocument($auth);
        echo $parser;
```

В чем ошибка?Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

302 код означает, что документ недоступен по текущему адресу, но был передан заголовок Location с адресом, в котором доступен этот документ.

Чтобы CURL автоматический перешел по данному URL, добавьте в код, перед curl_exec:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , true);
```

Comment: помогло,но теперь другая проблема - автоматический редирект на сам сайт после выгрузки